# Is there a way to determine checked radio button before form submission?

Tags: javascript, forms, stripe-payments

I'm working on creating a dynamic Stripe checkout form. I would like the form to change based on a radio button selection. Here is the code I have so far. I removed some of the stripe code that is unnecessary for this question, but it's in there and works on my end.

```
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
            <form id="payment-form" method="post" action="procedures/charge.php" >
                <input id="monthly" type="radio" name="plan-id" value="monthly1" > $10/month<br>
                <input id="annual" type="radio" name="plan-id" value="annual1" > $89/year<br>
                <button type="submit" id="customButton">Sign Up</button>
            </form>
            <script>              

            document.getElementById('customButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {

             //This is where I'm having my problem

              var plan = document.querySelector('input[name = "plan-id"]:checked').value;
            if(plan = 'monthly1') {
              var description = 'Monthly Subscription';
              var amount = 1000;
            }else if(plan = 'annual1') {
              var description = 'Annual Subscription';
              var amount = 8900;
            }  
              // Open Checkout with further options:
              handler.open({
                name: 'Your Strength Coach',
                description: description,
                amount: amount,
                email: '<?php echo $user['email'] ?>',
              });
              e.preventDefault();
            });
            </script>
```

My problem comes when I try to test for which radio is checked to assign the variables in the handler.open section. I have add "checked" to either input, the code works with that default. But it will not register a change if I select something other than that "checked" item.

For example, if the monthly1 radio has the checked property, I can't get the code to notice I selected the annual1 option and use that portion of the if statement.

Is there a way to determine which button is selected at this stage in the operation?

Comment: `if(plan = 'monthly1')` should have `===` or `==` comparison operators, you are using assignment operator...

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I'm an idiot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand. The checked property means you have selected that item, if you select something else after selecting some item, the checked property will also change accordingly.

The reason it is not working is because of what Rayon said in the comment, you are using assignment operator instead of equals operator. (= v/s == or ===)

Comment: You're correct. Rayon's comment was the solution. Thank you for the help and excuse my ignorance/carelessness.